# The Nodejs generate snapshot file size is 0

Tags: node.js

I want to generate a dump snapshot of a Node.js (`v16.20.2`) application. My application was running in Docker and mounted the NAS path `/opt/data`. First I added the dump function [from this tutorial](https://dev.to/bengl/node-js-heap-dumps-in-2021-5akm) like this:

```
const memorySnapshot = () => {
  const snapshotStream = v8.getHeapSnapshot()
  // It's important that the filename end with `.heapsnapshot`,
  // otherwise Chrome DevTools won't open it.
  const fileName = `/opt/data/y-websocket-dump/${Date.now()}.heapsnapshot`
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)
  snapshotStream.pipe(fileStream)
}
```

Then I invoked this function by send a http request. Everything works fine, the dump was generated in the path, but now I found the dump file size is 0:

```
[root@k8smasterone y-websocket-dump]# ls -alh
total 1.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Oct  7 00:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K Oct  7 00:04 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct  7 00:15 1696608905060.heapsnapshot
```

Am I missing something? What should I do to fix this issue?